# Two NSFetchedResultsControllers with the same fetch request doesn't return the same fetched objects

Tags: core-data

I have two NSFetchedResultsControllers in my app, and they perform the same fetch. i.e. the fetch request, managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath and cacheName of the two frcs are exactly the same.
However, they return two different sets of managed objects as fetched objects.
One is :

```
<_PFArray 0x175106e0>(
<Item: 0x17511360> (entity: Item; id: 0x175125e0 <x-coredata://5C2547EC-0420-4ED5-867D-087DEF4998EA/Item/p580> ; data: {resourceType = 0;}),
<Item: 0x17510fb0> (entity: Item; id: 0x17512560 <x-coredata://5C2547EC-0420-4ED5-867D-087DEF4998EA/Item/p581> ; data: <fault>),
)
```

The other one:

```
<_PFBatchFaultingArray 0x18a6fac0>(
<Item: 0x17511360> (entity: Item; id: 0x175125e0 <x-coredata://5C2547EC-0420-4ED5-867D-087DEF4998EA/Item/p587> ; data: {resourceType = 0;}),
<Item: 0x176946a0> (entity: Item; id: 0x18a7f860 <x-coredata://5C2547EC-0420-4ED5-867D-087DEF4998EA/Item/p590> ; data: <fault>),
)
```

According to the apple's documentation, 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html
,I am expecting the two fetch object arrays to contain same managed objects.

What could be wrong? Thanks!

Update: I've noticed that the two fired MOs are the same one, but the faults are different.

Comment: But retrieved values are the same? Didi you check this in the console? Show us the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I guess it's a caching issue. Basically there are two ways:

1. do a performFetch on both NSFetchedResultsControllers before accessing fetchedObjects array
2. set a delegate for both NSFetchedResultsControllers